# Zorn's Lemma And Axiom of Choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

How can I prove Zorn's lemma is equivalent to Axiom of choice?

Comment: Have you tried googling it? I did and got a few good links: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/axiom-choice/#MaxPriZorLem
http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/ProofOfZornsLemma.html

Comment: I am against closing the question.
As the user who voted to close did not leave an explanation, I can only guess what his reasons were. If it was because this result can be found in many standard references, I do not think this is good enough reason. I believe we have plenty of such questions. If, for example, the proof that that *identity is unique in a group* is not too trivial for this site, the proof of equivalence of AC and ZL is definitely not too trivial.

Comment: George Bergman has a nice handout proving the equivalence of Zorn's Lemma, the Axiom of Choice, the Well-Ordering Theorem, and Bernstein's Theorem; it is in postcript, and [here's a link to it](http://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/grad.hndts/AC+Zorn+.ps).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Assume the axiom of choice. Let $(P,\le)$ a partially ordered set that every chain has an upper bound. Let $f$ to be a choice function from all non-empty subsets of $P$, and let $P_a = \{x\in P\mid a<x\}$ then $P_a=\varnothing$ if and only if $a$ is a maximal element.

We define by using transfinite induction:

Let $a_0$ be an element of $P$, if it is maximal then we have finished. Otherwise $P_0 = \{x\in P\mid a_0<x\}$ is non-empty, let $a_1 = f(P_0)$.

Suppose $a_\alpha$ was defined, if it is maximal then we are done, otherwise $P_\alpha=\{x\in P\mid a_\alpha<x\}$ is non-empty and $a_{\alpha+1} = f(P_\alpha)$.

If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, and for all $\beta<\alpha$ we have chosen $a_\beta$, then $\{a_\beta\mid \beta<\alpha\}$ is a chain without a maximal element in $P$, and therefore bounded with an upper bound above all the elements of the chain, thus $\bigcap_{\beta<\alpha} P_\beta\neq\varnothing$, and let $a_\alpha=f(\bigcap_{\beta<\alpha} P_\beta)$.

We argue that this must stop at some point, otherwise we have an injection from the proper class of the ordinals into the set $P$. Why did the process stop? It can only stop if we have reached a maximal element at some $a_\gamma$, as wanted.

---

Assume Zorn's lemma, and let $X$ be a non-empty collection of non-empty sets. Let $(C,\subseteq)$ be the set of all choice functions from some elements of $X$.

This is a non-empty set, since we can always choose from finitely many sets. Given a chain of choice functions, the union is indeed a function. So the condition of Zorn's lemma is satisfied. We have a maximal element $f$.

If $f$ is not a choice function from all the members of $X$ then we can extend it to one more element, which contradicts the maximality.

Comment: Can you explain: *If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, and for all $\beta<\alpha$ we have chosen $a_{\beta}$, then $\{a_{\beta} : \beta<\alpha\}$ is a chain* ***without a maximal element in $P$,$\ldots$*** [I don't get last part here.]

Comment: You've build a well-ordered chain that is isomorphic to $\alpha$. But since $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, there is no maximal element.

Answer (score 22):

Even though this is a standard result, which can be found elsewhere (probably in most standard textbooks and lecture notes on set theory); I think some brief discussion and giving some pointers could be useful.

Perhaps the first important thing is to stress that when you want show that something is equivalent to [Axiom of Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_Choice), you have to work in an axiomatic systems where AC is not an axiom. I would say [ZF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory)  is used most frequently.

The proof of ZL $\Rightarrow$ AC is similar to most applications of [Zorn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma). We want to show that there exists a selector (choice function). This selector is obtained from ZL as maximal partial selector. So the only thing is to show that union of a chain (w.r.t. inclusion) of partial functions, which select one element from each set is again such a function.

The proof of AC $\Rightarrow$ ZL which I like best relies on [transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction). We assume that there is a set which fulfills the assumptions of ZL and has no maximal elements. In this way we inductively construct a chain with no upper bound. The use of AC is to select some element from the non-empty set of upper bounds of already selected elements in each step. This kind of proof assumes that we already know something about ordinals and transfinite induction; but I think that this technique is very useful in general.

However, for various reasons, some authors prefer to avoid using transfinite induction. As an example I can mention the papers of Weston and Lewin bellow. As I mentioned, the proof can be found in almost all standard textbooks. I've included Devlin and Halmos, to give at least one example of a book which uses ordinals in this proof and one example of a book which avoids them.

Some references:

- J. D. Weston: A short proof of Zorn's Lemma, Archiv der Mathematik, Volume 8, Number 4, 279, DOI: [10.1007/BF01898788](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01898788). One page long proof of AC $\Rightarrow$ ZL without using transfinite induction.
- Lewin, J. (1991). A simple proof of Zorn's lemma. The American Mathematical Monthly, 98(4), pp. 353-354. [jstor](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323807)  Another short proof of AC $\Rightarrow$ ZL avoiding the use of ordinals.
- K. Devlin: Joy of Sets. Theorem 2.7.5 on [p.60](https://books.google.com/books?id=hCv-vFu4jskC&pg=PA60) gives the proof of AC $\Rightarrow$ ZL using transfinite induction. The opposite implications is given as a series of implications in theorems following this one.
- P. Halmos: Naive Set Theory, [p.62](https://books.google.com/books?id=x6cZBQ9qtgoC&pg=PA63). Halmos chooses approach avoiding the transfinite induction.

Comment: A proof of AC$\Rightarrow$ ZL using [Bourbaki-Witt theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourbaki%E2%80%93Witt_theorem) was mentioned in
[another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128649/bourbaki-witt-fixed-point-theorem-two-questions)

Comment: can you refer me to a proof for ZL $\Longrightarrow$ AC?

Comment: @Jneven There are many sources where this proof can be found. (I'd guess that it should be in most standard textbooks of set theory.) Anyway, we can discuss this [in set theory chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2318/2019/2/26) - I'll post there some suggestions I am able to find.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathscr{P}}\newcommand{\C}{\mathscr{C}}\newcommand{\A}{\mathcal{A}}$I am posting this just to flesh out some details in the proof in [Bergman's handout](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egbergman/grad.hndts/AC+Zorn+.ps). The motivation for this proof is to capture the concept of a transfinite sequence without doing any explicit work with transfinite stuff. I still don't really know about that, so this proof appealed to me, but for my own sake I felt it needed simplification: this posting is as much for my own benefit as I hope it might be for any future readers.

Note that I allow, for convenience, "chains" in a poset to be empty. Similarly I allow "well ordered" sets to be empty and I allow "initial segments" to be empty. Otherwise, these terms carry their standard meanings below.

---

Zorn's lemma:

> If a poset $(\P,\prec)$ has the property that all chains $C\subseteq\P$ have an upper bound, then $\P$ has a maximal element.

Note taking $C=\emptyset$ implies $\P$ is at least nonempty.

Proof:

> For the sake of contradiction, suppose no maximal element exists.
>
> Fix a choice function $\phi$ on $2^{\P}\setminus\{\emptyset\}$. For any chain $C\subseteq\P$, the set $U(C):=\{x\in\P:\forall y\in C,\,y\prec x\}$ is nonempty. For there is an upper bound $m$ to $C$, and since $m$ is not maximal there is $m'\in\P$ with $m\prec m'$. Then $m'\in U(C)$.
>
> If $\C$ denotes the set of all chains in $\P$, we have a valid function $\upsilon:\C\to\P$ taking $C\mapsto\phi(U(C))$. This will do the magic picking of larger elements for us.
>
> Say $A\subseteq\P$ is an "attempt" if it is well ordered and if for all proper subchains $C$ of $A$, $\min A\setminus C=\upsilon(C)$. The motivation for this is explained better in the linked handout, but think of these "attempts" as transfinite sequences in disguise which attempt to reach a maximal element.
>
> Suppose there are two attempts $A,A'$ with neither contained in the other; then define $\zeta=\min A\setminus A'$, $\zeta’=\min A’\setminus A$. With no loss of generality say $\zeta’$ is not less than $\zeta$. Consider $C:=\{x\in A:x\prec\zeta\}$: it is contained in both $A$ and $A’$ so by hypothesis it cannot equal either of them. $C$ shall then a proper initial segment of both $A$ and $A’$, using the fact that no element of $A’\setminus A$ can be less than $\zeta$.
>
> But then we have: $$A\setminus A’\ni\zeta=\min A\setminus C=\upsilon(C)=\min A'\setminus C\in A'$$Which is absurd. Therefore for any two attempts $A,A'$, it is true that $A\subseteq A'$ or visa versa. With the same notation, in the situation $A’\subseteq A$ we find $C=A’$ is forced: $C$ is an initial segment of both $A,A’$ so the event that it is properly contained in $A’$ is impossible by the same reasoning.
>
> We get to conclude that for any pair of attempts, one will be an initial segment of the other.
>
> With this important fact proven, we can now prove that the union of any set $\A$ of attempts is an attempt:
>
> Let $S\subseteq\bigcup\A$ be nonempty. For some $A_0\in\A$, $S\cap A_0$ is nonempty and has a minimum $\varsigma$ in $A_0$. If $A\in\A\setminus\{A_0\}$ and $A\subseteq A_0$, then $\varsigma$ remains a minimum for $S\cap A$ trivially; else, $A_0$ is a proper initial segment of $A$, so there cannot exist $x\in A\setminus A_0$ with $x\prec\varsigma$ and $\varsigma$ is still a minimum for $S\cap A$. Hence $\min S=\varsigma$ exists and $\bigcup\A$ is well ordered.
>
> If $C$ is a proper initial segment of $\bigcup\A$ then with $S:=\bigcup\A\setminus C$, we know $\min S=\min S\cap A_0$ for some (any) $A_0\in\A$ satisfying $S\cap A_0\neq\emptyset$. There is $y\in A_0\setminus C$, necessarily. Suppose that $C$ is not contained in $A_0$, that there is also $x\in C\setminus A_0$. Then $x\in A$ for some attempt $A\in\A$ which must contain $A_0$ and $C':=C\cap A$ and $A_0$ are both initial segments of $A$.
>
> Because $x\in C'\setminus A_0$, $y\in A_0\setminus C'$, the initial segment property allows both cases $x\prec y$ and $y\prec x$ to be ruled out - but since $A$ is well ordered, one of these must occur. This contradiction implies that $C$ *is* contained in $A_0$, hence it is a proper initial segment of $A_0$. Then we have: $$\min\bigcup\A\setminus C=\min S\cap A_0=\min A_0\setminus C=\upsilon(C)$$As desired.
>
> Finally, take $\A$ to be the set of all attempts in $\P$: by the above, $\alpha:=\bigcup\A$ is an attempt and indeed the *largest* possible attempt. In particular $\alpha$ is also a chain, so $\upsilon(\alpha)$ exists (this is the whole reason for the song-and-dance about “attempts”, is so that the hypothetical largest [thing] is actually a chain and we can derive a contradiction). Since $\upsilon(\alpha)$ is a strict upper bound for $\alpha$, it is clear $\alpha\cup\{\upsilon(\alpha)\}$ (this is where the usual transfinite "add another element to the sequence" principle appears) is a strictly larger attempt than $\alpha$ - a contradiction!
>
> $\blacksquare$

Comment: I didn't read the full post, but I would have thought that according to the standard definitions of "chains", "initial segments", and "well ordered sets", all three of them are allowed to be empty. For example, $\varnothing$ (together with the empty relation) is well-ordered because it is vacuously true that every non-empty subset of $\varnothing$ has a least element.

Comment: @Joe I would agree, but in reading around and I think also in Bergman’s handout I found nonemptiness was emphasised (unduly?) so I thought I should just make clear my conventions. It’s easy to forget about the emptyset