# Does Tychonov's theorem imply Zorn's lemma

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

I know that Tychonov's theorem, Zorn's lemma, the axiom of choice, the well-ordering theorem and many other results are *logically equivalent* in the sense that either of them implies all other in ZF. But this is not my question.

I would like to know if there is a **direct proof** of Zorn's lemma using Tychonov's theorem for a suitably constructed produt of compact spaces.

I am sure that everybody understands the question although it is hard to *formalize* what I want. But again, this is not the point of this question.

Comment: The set theorists tell me we need the axiom of choice to even know the arbitrary product is nonempty

Comment: Would you be satisfied with a *direct* proof of Tychonov $\Rightarrow$ AC, or do you really want Zorn?

Comment: No, I **don't want** Tychonov $\Rightarrow$ AC $\Rightarrow$ Zorn but a **direct proof** Tychonov $\Rightarrow$ Zorn.

Comment: My first idea is to start with a poset $X$, and consider the left order topology on well-ordered subsets of $X$ (maybe well-ordered sets that have a particular $p$ as least element). The compact ones would be the ones with a maximum. Then we can consider a suitable subcollection (mirroring the idea that we have a well-ordered subset with a maximum; if the maximum is not maximal in $X$, then adjoin a larger element...) and look at their product.

Comment: What about a direct proof that Tychonoff's theorem implies Zorn's lemma by proving that it implies AC and then proving that implies Zorn's lemma, but without formally stating it as two steps?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Maybe not quite as heavy handed, but perhaps Kelly's proof that TT implies AC could be used so "select" appropriate upper bounds and obtain the maximal element.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am quite sure that you understand that this would not be the answer I am hoping for. The idea of Arturo Magidin is much more on topic.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

Given a partially ordered set $P$ with the property that every chain has an upper bound, for each chain $C$ let $X_C=\{C\}\cup\{p\in P:\forall c\in C(p> c)\}$. Topologize each $X_C$ with your favorite compact topology that has $C$ isolated (such as $\{\emptyset,\{C\},X_C\}$). By Tychonoff's theorem, $X=\prod_{C} X_C$ is compact.

Note if $X_C\setminus \{C\}$ is empty for some chain $C$, then $C$'s upper bound is a maximal element of $P$, and we're done. So suppose not. For each finite collection of chains $\mathcal F$, $H_{\mathcal F}=\prod_{C} H_{C,\mathcal F}$ defined by $H_{C,\mathcal F}=X_C\setminus\{C\}$ for $C\in\mathcal F$ and $H_{C,\mathcal F}=X_C$ otherwise is a closed subset of $X$ since $\{C\}$ is open in $X_C$. Each $H_{\mathcal F}$ is nonempty: let $f(C)\in X_C\setminus\{C\}\not=\emptyset$ be arbitrary for (importantly, to not require AC, finitely-many) $C\in \mathcal F$, and let $f(C)=C\in X_C$ otherwise. Since $H_{\mathcal F_1}\cap H_{\mathcal F_2}=H_{\mathcal F_1\cup \mathcal F_2}$, the finite intersection of $H_{\mathcal F}$s is also nonempty.

By the [FIP characterization of compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property#Compactness), $\bigcap_{C} H_{C}=\prod_{C}X_C\setminus\{C\}$ is non-empty; choose some $g\in\bigcap_{C} H_C$ and note $g(C)>c$ for all $c\in C$.

We will now embed an order-isomoprhic copy of the class of all ordinals into the set $P$ to obtain our contradiction. First choose $p_0\in P$. Suppose $p_\beta\in P$ has been chosen for all $\beta<\alpha$ such that $p_\gamma<p_\beta$ for all $\gamma<\beta<\alpha$. Then $C_\alpha=\{p_\beta:\beta<\alpha\}$ is a chain, and we may define $p_\alpha=g(C_\alpha)$ where $p_\beta<p_\alpha$ for all $\beta<\alpha$.

Thus we have constructed $\{p_\alpha:\alpha\in\mathbf{On}\}\cong\mathbf{On}$ with $\{p_\alpha:\alpha\in\mathbf{On}\}\subseteq P$, obtaining our contraction.

---

This proof was obtained essentially by remixing [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem#Proof_of_the_axiom_of_choice_from_Tychonoff%27s_theorem) with [this Math.StackExchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/97315).

Comment: This tacitly uses the axiom of choice to pick $p_\alpha$ when $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal.

Comment: Does it? Admittedly I take AC for granted usually so I'm sloppy about using it, but I don't believe there's a problem using the assumption that a single chain must have an upper bound and giving it a name at a given stage of transfinite induction.

Comment: But why is the upper bound unique? If it is not, then among all the possible upper bounds, which one are you calling $p_\alpha$?

Comment: I didn't intend to claim it's unique. My argument is that at each stage of the induction, I have a set of upper bounds, and by assumption this set is non-empty, so I must be able to pick one. I believe (emphasis on believe!) I'm not using a choice function as I'm not doing this simultaneously for infinitely-many non-empty sets.

Comment: Of course, I can exploit Tychonoff's theorem again in any case: for each chain C I take its non-empty set S of upper bounds, topologize $S\cup \{C\}$ to be compact with C isolated, etc etc.

Comment: I've made an edit that I believe circumvents the issue.

Comment: No, still using choice. :-)

Comment: Ha, well, I'll make this a community wiki in case it's easily fixed, as I'd need a hint to fix it myself I suppose.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your ideas, Steven. I was hoping for a proof not relying on transfinite induction.

Comment: You need to prove that $X$ is not empty, too.

Comment: There's no need to use all ordinals; you'll be done before Hartogs' aleph of $P$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number)

Comment: @StevenClontz  Plus, you're cheating you first show that there is a choice function and then go through a proof of "AC implies Zorn". Can you prove topologically that there are enough maximal elements?